# useSelector and dispatch using persist redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using persist redux to save the state of some states after refresh.

However, I'm having trouble accessing the values using these tools.

For example, using a simple redux toolkit I can simply do:

```
const userId = useSelector((state) => state)
```

However, when using a persist reducer, it returns `undefined`.

Here's my code for store:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import idReducer from './idSlice'
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage' // defaults to localStorage for web
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'


const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, idReducer)

let store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer, 
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  middleware: [thunk]
});

export default store;
```

index.js:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
let persistor = persistStore(store)

root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>
);
```

Here's what I have for dispatch (doesn't seem to work either)

```
const handleClick = (id) => {
    console.log("dispatch ", id)
    dispatch(setId(id))
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: *What* exactly is undefined? Can you [edit] to include better/clearer details and a more complete [mcve] that includes all the redux code you are working with?

Answer (score -1):

You said
`I am using persist redux to save the state of some states after refresh`.
Redux does not keep anything after refresh. Its store lives in JavaScript, so when the code is triggered to run again, everything restarts.

The first important thing is to consider not refreshing at all. I mean keep a high order component, and re-render the components below it.

The second way is to save the necessary values on `localStorage`, or `sessionStorage` (the difference is that while data in localStorage doesn't expire, data in sessionStorage is cleared when the page session ends, found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)) or on your database on the backend.

Normally user's data (not risky data, like token) is saved on `localStorage` so user wouldn't have to sign in every time.

Comment: Did you look at the snippets? It appears he is using a library called [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) which essentially is a wrapper around your second suggestion.

Comment: @noviceGuru I would love to not consider refreshing at all, but that's up to the users to decide, not me. Hence I must consider the fact that the users could force a refresh, and I would have to deal with that.